# How to validate struct creation?

Tags: validation, struct, rust

I'm working through [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/). I'm currently at [`TryFrom` and `TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/conversion/try_from_try_into.html). This is their code:

```
struct EvenNumber(i32);

impl TryFrom<i32> for EvenNumber {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(value: i32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value % 2 == 0 {
            Ok(EvenNumber(value))
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation prevents the creation of an instance of `EvenNumber` with an odd number, but only if I call `try_from` (or `try_into`). I can still create an `EvenNumber(1337)` directly.

In Java (and related languages), one would validate instance creation inside a constructor, e.g.:

```java
class EvenNumber {
    public final int value;

    public EvenNumber(int value) {
        if (value % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("value is odd");
        }
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

How to do this in Rust?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd define `EvenNumber` inside some module and keep its `num` field private, so the only way people can create instances of `EvenNumber` would be through a public method you control, like `new`. Example:

```rust
mod some_mod {
    pub struct EvenNumber {
        num: i32,
    }
    
    impl EvenNumber {
        pub fn new(num: i32) -> Result<Self, ()> {
            if num % 2 == 0 {
                Ok(EvenNumber {
                    num,
                })
            } else {
                Err(())
            }
        }
    }
}

// bring EvenNumber into scope
use some_mod::EvenNumber;

fn try_to_create_invalid_even_number() -> EvenNumber {
    EvenNumber {
        num: 1337, // compile error
    }
}
```

Throws:

```
error[E0451]: field `num` of struct `EvenNumber` is private
  --> src/lib.rs:24:9
   |
24 |         num: 1337,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ private field
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67b6783c45ea0fdc2e9747b608470c62)

Comment: Seems logical. I haven't arrived at the module chapter yet. But how do I access `num` from outside the module? Do I have to write a getter?

Comment: @xehpuk pretty much

Answer (score 5):

When your tuple struct is defined in a different module (which can be simply a different file) or like the following:

```
mod mod_name {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct EvenNumber(i32);
    
    use std::convert::TryFrom;
    impl TryFrom<i32> for EvenNumber {
        type Error = ();

        fn try_from(value: i32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
            if value % 2 == 0 {
                Ok(EvenNumber(value))
            } else {
                Err(())
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let num = mod_name::EvenNumber(5); // error[E0603]: tuple struct constructor `EvenNumber` is private
    
    use std::convert::TryFrom;
    let num = mod_name::EvenNumber::try_from(4);
    println!("num = {:?}", num.unwrap());
}
```

Then you wouldn't be able to construct that tuple directly with any number. You can test this by uncommenting the commented line in the above example. In Rust, the privacy of entities matter only towards the sibling or parental modules but not towards the same scope or children modules.